# AngularJS AJAX call to a servlet in JAVA

Tags: angularjs, servlets

My class in the project is under a package com.project.controller and the name of the servlet class is UpdateDatabaseController. The corresponding code of the web.xml is,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UpdateDatabaseController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.project.controller.UpdateDatabaseController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UpdateDatabaseController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UpdateDB</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

In the html page, I have a button that is calling a function, updateDatabase(). And the code of the script is:

```
$scope.updateDatabase = function(){
        $http.get('/UpdateDB').success(function(data) {
            alert("Controller hit");
        });
    };
```

Whenever I hit the button, the error in the browser log is displayed, that :
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/UpdateDB"

I want that on my button click, the POST method of the servlet class is invoked. But the error is fixed in the browser log. I am unable to solve this situation.

Comment: you miss ProjectName in ur URL http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/UpdateDB

Comment: How can I do include that in the URL?

Comment: as i wrote localhost:8080/ProjectName/Servletmapping

Comment: I got it correct. But suppose I want to call a particular method in the servlet, shall I append the name of the method behind the URL?

Comment: Search 4 RestFul webServices that's 'll help check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431669/spring-mvc-rest-angularjs/28435116#28435116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss ProjectName in ur URL `localhost:8080/ProjectName/UpdateDB`

Comment: @ Ahmed Adel I added project name in the URL. That s also not working. See my local url 
 localhost:8080/AngularJSAll/03_AjaxCall/3.1_ajax_contoller/ajaxFile.jsp

Comment: we are talking here about calling a servlet using angularjs, why you are refer to jsp page

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.updateDatabase = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost/YourProject/UpdateDB').success(function(data) {
            alert("Controller hit");
        });
    };
```

I had the same problem, and fixed it by adding `http://` in front of the link.